# XSLT to create node only field exist

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where i need to consider node (Node name : LineItem) only when one of the its element (sequenceNumber) exists, remaining all the LineItems we need to remove.
I tried below, but its not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LineItem[sequenceNumber]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>``
```

Comment: For future reference, it's useful to show your input XML and your expected results. And rather than saying "it's not working" it's useful to tell us exactly how it fails.

Comment: yeah sure, apologies for not posting the input XML

Answer (score 0):

try with xsl:choose

```
<xsl:template match="LineItem">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=".//sequenceNumber">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<!-- skip element -->
</xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not getting the result.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfT                 not getting the result

Comment: please check updated answer - https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfT/1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<xsl:template match="LineItem[sequenceNumber]"/>` I think you want `<xsl:template match="LineItem[not(sequenceNumber)]"/>` or, based on your comment, if the other element can occur as a descendant, you need `<xsl:template match="LineItem[not(.//sequenceNumber)]"/>`.

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfL/3   giving different result

Comment: @Sree, see the edit, without knowing your XML structure which you did not show in your question it is hard to guess which XPath expression or XSLT pattern you need.

Comment: from next time i will post with input details,  but your comment worked.. thank you somuch.